# Modifying an integer in an array of integers

Tags: c

If I have a an array of `int`s, how could I directly edit each `int`?

```
int i = arr + 1; // Getting the integer in pos 1
```

`i` is just a copy, correct? If I set `i = 4`, then `arr + 1` would still be `1`.

Would this work?

```
int *i = &(arr + 1);
*i = 4;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the array operators:

```
int i = arr[1];
arr[1] = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got:

```
int arr[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

---

Want to edit it further?

```
arr[0] = 42;

// arr[] = {42, 1, 2, 3};
```

---

Want to change all of them at once? There's:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    arr[i] = i * 2;

// arr[] = {0, 2, 4, 6};
```

---

And don't forget [`memset()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/)!

```
memset(arr, 42, 4);

// arr[] = {42, 42, 42, 42};
```

---

Want to change everything but the first element to `7`?

```
memset(&arr[1], 7, 4 - 1);

// arr[] = {42, 7, 7, 7};
```

---

---

Would you like to know somethin' about [pointers](http://xkcd.com/138/)? ([Here's a more useful link.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/))

See this? (If you can't, please stop reading this. Thanks!)

```
int *ptr = &arr[1];
```

It's equivalent to:

```
int *ptr = arr + 1;
```

Which is also equivalent to:

```
int *ptr = arr;
ptr = ptr + 1;
```

---

OK, now that we've got that down, let's show you a more efficient for-loop than the one I did above:

```
int *ptr = arr;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    *ptr = i << 2;
    // i * 2 == i << 2

    ++ptr;
}

// arr[] = {0, 2, 4, 6};
```

Not that you should code like that; the compiler will handle it for you, most likely.

---

Would you like another answer in the form of a series of questions?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
int *i = arr + 1;
*i = 4;
```

and it will work. Arrays in C are just pointers to first element in the array. 
So this `arr + 0`  will give address of first element in array and this `arr + 1` is an address of second element.

Answer (score 0):

Array indexing operators can do what you need.

```
arr[3] = 101; //assignment to array
int x = arr[37]; //get value from array
```

etc.

No need for for that memory arithmetic here..

Comment: I think you meant to say 'address arithmetic' instead of 'memory arithmetic'

Comment: yes thatd be better way to say it.  or maybe pointer arithmetic